# Special considerations for a new Certificate Authority with multiple UPN suffices?

Tags: certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

Our AD domain is foo.com, NetBIOS FOO_D1. A previous employee added a second UPN suffix, bar.com. Our corporate identity now revolves around bar.com, such that it is used in everyone's email address. All new users get a UPN with the bar.com suffix. We have not migrated existing foo.com AD users over to bar.com but this is planned (they *do*, however, use bar.com email).

We have an existing CA set up on one of our domain controllers (2008 R2) for foo.com. To my knowledge, we are not using that CA for anything, and that DC is slated to be removed once all our 2012 DCs are up and running.

We now have the need to actually use our CA to start deploying certificates for network access (and I would like to start enabling digital signing for mail users).

I'm setting up a new CA, but I intend to set this up for bar.com and not foo.com. I assume I can change the common name and the distinguished name, but since there's not actually an LDAP path for DC=bar,DC=com, I'm guessing that won't work the way I think it does. I'm expecting that AD won't actually be able to store the key information since that LDAP path doesn't exist.

So, am I even able to do what I'm trying to accomplish here? Do I need to add some sort of referral link in LDAP so that DC=bar,DC=com works? Do our foo.com users have to be migrated for this to work?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what is the problem. "I assume I can change the common name and the distinguished name" -- which name? CA cert name? "able to store the key information since that LDAP path doesn't exist" what kind of keys you talk about?

Comment: So, when I set up the CA via the wizard, I'm given default values to label the CA itself. The defaults for this are - Common name: bar-HOSTNAME-CA, Distinguished name suffix: DC=foo,DC=com, Distinguished name: CN=bar-HOSTNAME-CA,DC=foo,DC=com. Because we are basically working toward using bar exclusively, I would expect that I should change the suffix here to reflect that I'm using bar.com rather than foo.com, but since there's no container named DC=bar,DC=com, I'm assuming this doesn't work. At the core, my problem may be more a question of "How can I overlay additional UPN suffices in LDAP?"

Comment: Distinguished name in the CA cert can be whatever you want, it doesn't relate to Active Directory domain path. In general, I recommend to put company information in the DN. For example "CompanyXYZ Class 2 Root CA, OU=Division of IT, O=CompanyXYZ, S=PA, L=Philadelphia, C=US".